# Proof of funds for Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm applying for a Schengen visa for a ten-day trip and the webpage of the embassy specifically requires six months of checking account statements and they DO NOT accept savings account statements. However, I do not put money in my checking account and I always transfer the balance each month to my savings account. So the balance of my checking is usually less than $50 each month.

What do I do in this case?

On the webpage, under the requirements for proof of funds, there's a link to a different webpage explaining the details of the requirements, they also take credit cards and cash.

So I should take cash to the embassy?

And credit cards statements showing credit limit?

Comment: what's your nationality?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you still have a checking account with some funds come to it, and only after that you transfer it to your savings account.
So these funds will appear on your account's statement, and this will be enough for the embassy, as they will able to see your income, either from direct deposit or some other methods you get your funds.

Comment: @CindyL It's great to say thanks, but please extend 'VMAtm' the proper courtesy consistent with the way the site works. I.e., please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to bank and ask for six months of checking account statement in purpose of applying for visa, it will show cache flow on your account. I don't know how big is your income, but if you applying just for 10 days of stay that will be enough I'm sure. 
This will also show that you have regular income so it's more likely that you will return back to your country and you will have bigger chances to get visa approval.